# Create a new array object base on existing array

Tags: c#

I have a existing array of object(animals), and i want to loop through the array and create a new list of object(dog).The following are my code, just wondering if there is a nice way to tidy up the code, so i will become one line.

```
      var dogs = new List<dog>();
                animals.ForEach(item => dogs.Add(new
                    dog()
                    {
                        dog.name = item.name
                    }));
```

expected

```
new List<dog>() 
{
  animals.....
}
```

Comment: May be *Linq*? `var dogs = animals.Select(item => new dog() {name = item.name}).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LinQ to get the list of strings for a List of object type. However, LinQ runs a for loop in the background.

```
var dogs= animals.Select(x=> new dog() {name = x.name}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically I would expect a Dog inherits from an Animal class and if you know all your animals are dogs then you can Cast:

```
var dogs = animals.Cast<Dog>();
```

Or you can get only Dogs from Animals:

```
var dogs = animals.OfType<Dog>();
```

In other words, your list is expected to be generated something like:

```
var animals = new List<Animal> {
   new Dog {Name="Shephard"},
   new Dog {Name="Whisky"},
};
```

and you could use Cast(). Or if it was:

```
var animals = new List<Animal> {
   new Dog {Name="Shephard"},
   new Dog {Name="Whisky"},
   new Cat {Name="Garfield"}
};
```

you could use OfType(). If neither then you would need to generate a new List like:

```
   var dogs = animals // .Where(x => x.IsDog(...))
              .Select(x => new Dog {Name = x.Name
                                           // , X = x.X, 
                                           // ...
                           });
```